# First time using Bitbucket Pipeline. PyTest file or directory not found: tests/*

Tags: python, pytest, bitbucket-pipelines

This is my first time using Bitbucket Pipeline to build a python program.
The code I have is this:

```
image: python:3.8.11

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install dependencies
        script:
          - if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - step:
        name: PyTest
        script:
          - pip install pytest
          - pytest -v tests/* --junitxml=test-reports\report.xml
    - step:
        name: Unit test
        script:
          - python -m unittest discover tests-reports/
    - step:
        name: Django test
        script:
          - pip install django
          - python manage.py test
    - step:
        name: Lint code
        script:
          # Enforce style consistency across Python projects https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/manpage.html
          - pip install flake8
          - flake8 . --extend-exclude=dist,build --show-source --statistics
```

The first step "Install dependencies" passes. But the second step "PyTest" fails. Here is the error message:

```
+ pytest -v tests/* --junitxml=test-reports\report.xml
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.11, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
collecting ... collected 0 items
- generated xml file: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/test-reportsreport.xml -
============================ no tests ran in 0.00s =============================
ERROR: file or directory not found: tests/*
```

I am not sure what is going on with pipeline and deployment as I am new to the process.
Can anyone let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it appears that the relative path to the tests/ directory cannot be found.  You could try changing your build script to use an absolute path.  Bitbucket provides access to default [variables](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/) that can be used to build an absolute path.

You would change:

```
- step:
        name: PyTest
        script:
          - pip install pytest
          - pytest -v tests/* --junitxml=test-reports\report.xml
```

To something like this (depending on your actual repo directory structure):

```
- step:
        name: PyTest
        script:
          - pip install pytest
          - pytest -v ${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/your/path/to/tests/* --junitxml=test-reports\report.xml
```